# How do I make this web crawler print only the titles of the songs?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    url = 'https://www.officialcharts.com/charts/singles-chart'
    reqs = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')

    urls = []
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        print(link.get('href'))

    def chart_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1

        while page >= max_pages:
            url = "https://www.officialcharts.com/charts/singles-chart"
            source_code = requests.get(url)
            plain_text = source_code.text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')

            for link in soup.findAll('a', {"class": "title"}):
                href = "BAD HABITS" + link.title(href)
                print(href)
        page += 1

    chart_spider(1)
```

Wondering how to make this print just the titles of the songs instead of the entire page. I want it to go through the top 100 charts and print all the titles for now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's is a possible solution, which modify your code as little as possible:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.officialcharts.com/charts/singles-chart'

def chart_spider():
    source_code = requests.get(URL)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
    for title in soup.find_all('div', {"class": "title"}):
        print(title.contents[1].string)

chart_spider()
```

The result is a list of all the titles found in the page, one per line.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the titles for each song on the top 100,
this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url='https://www.officialcharts.com/charts/singles-chart/'

req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

titles = [i.text.replace('\n', '') for i in soup.find_all('div', class_="title")]
```

does what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

- The Song title is present inside a `<div>` tag with class name as `title`.
- Select all those `<div>` with `.find_all()`. This gives you a list of all `<div>` tags.
- Iterate over the list and print the text of each div.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'https://www.officialcharts.com/charts/singles-chart/'
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

d = soup.find_all('div', class_='title')
for i in d:
    print(i.text.strip())
```

Sample Output:

```
BAD HABITS
STAY
REMEMBER
BLACK MAGIC
VISITING HOURS
HAPPIER THAN EVER
INDUSTRY BABY
WASTED
.
.
.
```